# Retrieve text from a textbox to place in another textbox on same windows form

Tags: c#, textbox

I have created a good windows form. What I have been asked to do is break it down some more. What I would like the users to be able to do is type in a `TextBox` but include some sort of tag that would represent text from another `TextBox`.

I have four text boxes:

1- `to_fromTextBox`

2- `city1TextBox`

3- `city2TextBox`

4- `enterTextbox`

So if a user types in `city1TextBox` - Orlando, then types in `city2TextBox` - Longwood.

Then while typing in `enterTextBox` - From (some tag to insert `city1TextBox`) to (some tag to insert `city1TextBox`) e.g. from *some identifier* to *some identifie*.

This would concatenate in `to_fromTextBox` to save in the database table. 
e.g. *From Orlando to Longwood*

The reason this has to be separate is when a report is created other textboxes will have map coordinates in it and will follow the city textboxes.
reported text e.g. *From Orlando (H-5) to Longwood (H-4)*

I have tried my best in searching for this answer with no luck. Could someone point me in the correct direction.

Comment: asp.net or win forms? your content and tags contradict.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Are you talking about manipulating text on your UI or how you persist data in your database?  I believe you have not clearly separated these concepts in your thinking yet.

Comment: ^^ and ##??? predefined them?

Comment: Something as simple as using #city1 and #city2 as tags, so when the user types "From #city1 to #city2", in the `Changed` event you look for those tags and replace them with the contents of the other textboxes.

Comment: Andrew - that seems almost too simple. I will give it a try.Thanks,

Comment: Why not use the tags {0} and {1} so you can use String.Format()?

Comment: @plint: :) that will be the best option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *^^* and *##* are predefined, you could write this code on **`keyup`** event of the `enterTextbox` like this

```
var text = "From ^^ to ##";
if (text.IndexOf("^^") != -1 && text.IndexOf("##") != -1)
{
    to_fromTextBox.Text = text
        .Replace("^^", city1TextBox.Text)
        .Replace("##", city2TextBox.Text);
}
```

But if you use *{0}* and *{1}* as identifiers, you could use [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format) like this

```
var text = "From {0} to {1}";
if (text.IndexOf("{0}") != -1 && text.IndexOf("{1}") != -1)
{
    to_fromTextBox.Text = String.Format(
        text, 
        city1TextBox.Text,
        city2TextBox.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the string in the textboxes with .Text (is a Get/Set, so you can change their values the same form).

```
textBox1.Text = "1"
textBoxt2.Text = "2"
textBoxN.Text = "n...";

textBoxTarget.Text = textBox1.Text +" - "+ textBoxt2.Text +" - "+ TextBoxN.Text;

textBoxTarget.Text = "1 - 2 - n..."
```